# Laravel Dusk test working in Development but failing in Production

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci, laravel-dusk

Hi everyone i have a Laravel app that runs it's CI through Gitlab CI and i have a problem my test using dusk runs fine in development on my machine but for some reason it fails whenever i push it to gitlab CI...

```
/** @test */
public function the_login_admin_route_should_login_the_user_with_valid_credentials()
{
    /** @var Admin $user */
    $user = factory(Admin::class)->create(['password' => bcrypt('secret')]);

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->visit("/admin/auth/login")
                ->type("email", $user->{Admin::FIELD_EMAIL})
                ->type("password", "secret")
                ->click("#login-button")
                ->waitForText("Logged in Successfully")
                ->waitForLocation("/admin/")
                ->assertPathIs("/admin/");
    });
}
```

That is the test in question and the part that fails specifically is the `waitForText` part.

I have another Dusk test that simply checks that when you try to go do `/dashboard` you get redirected to the login page and that one works fine i even do an `->assertSee("Login")` so i don't think the problem is *xvfb* but i'm deeply puzzled.

This is my gitlab CI config relative to the dusk tests

```
- chmod a+x ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
- xvfb-run ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux &
- sleep 5
- php artisan serve &
- npm install --silent
- npm run production
- php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan dusk --colors
```

I use Model factories to generate users as you could see and i already verified that the user is in fact created and exists in the Database using a `var_dump`

The text in question appears as part of a **Vuetify** *snackbar* component, kind of like a **toast** that appears and then flashes away after 5 seconds, again this all works fine on my machine so i don't think the component itself is the problem.

Does anyone have issues with the `waitForText` command when running their Dusk instances in headless environments like a CI docker container?

Comment: Update: I managed to get the tests passing by simply removing that waitForText part but i still dont quite understand what went wrong, perhaps Dusk has a hard time detecting these sorts "flashing" texts in XVFB environments for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different docker images for this, for example you can try this one...

In your .gitlab-ci.yml change

> image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable

BTW: Please post your errors...